# Unity build to UWP performance problems

Tags: c#, windows, unity-game-engine, uwp

I am having a problem with my unity build when targeting the Universal Windows Platform. The game runs perfectly (200+ FPS) on the regular x64 Windows build, but as soon as I run the build through the App packages or Visual Studio for UWP, I get only around 30 FPS with studders as well.

At first I thought it was a VSYNC issues, but the studdering makes me think otherwise, as well as the setting not being set in the graphics settings.

When I run the build on Xbox One with the app package, the system performance is the same as on PC, 30 FPS and some studdering. The system profiler on the Xbox One is saying that File I/O is causing some problems, so possiblly garbage collection?

As far as garbage collection goes, the worst thing that I would be doing is setting game objects as inactive/active through an object pool.

Any clues as to why the performance is so bad only on one platform? Or optimization tips for UWP specific?

Comment: File I/O sounds like disk usage to me, but garbage collection is going to be in memory stuff. So its probably not that. Are you doing a lot of loading? Are you assets hi res/large files that take a while to load?

Comment: No I'm not doing doing a lot of loading, the art assets are low poly style and don't have too much to them either, the GPU usage on the Xbox one is at around 60% at any time. 

Each level is a different scene, which is the only time that I load things. 

I load all the audio into a simple Singleton at the beginning of the game and set it to dont destroy on load, so that wouldn't be loading anything either